# D3js Add a half color on a rect element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

if have a rect a rect element that is covered with a dashed stroke on it and each one of them have a different color

[image-1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3i_LHuXTynaekpYX09CVFVCRG8/view)

the thing is that i want the background color only show up between a blank space

[image-2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3i_LHuXTynaTEd6STluSUt5SXc/view)

in the same rect element, is possible create this effect without create another rect elements over the current elements?

Comment: Sure, use a linear gradient with multiple stops to colour the rect

Comment: What attribute of d3 I can use for this?

Comment: fill (it's a CSS property too)

Comment: I have understood that i have to create linearGradient element over the rect to make the effect, but is possible just add the properties directly on the rect elements?

Comment: You could create the gradients as data URLs if you really wanted to. It's not very legible though.

Comment: You right, I going to try then